# How I can paste category id

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

how I can paste a category id in *IN HERE*? look at my code
I have a file named "categorylist.json" with IDs of categories. In this parameter *IN HERE* I need to insert a list of IDs from this file

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {
    if (oldState && newState) {
        if (oldState.channelID === newState.channelID) {
            return;
        }
    }
    if (oldState && oldState.channelID) {
        ChannelLeave(oldState.member, oldState.<IN HERE>.channels.resolve(oldState.channelID));
    }
    if (newState && newState.channelID) {
        ChannelJoin(newState.member, newState.<IN HERE>.channels.resolve(newState.channelID));
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the issue when doing just that?

Comment: I need to place category id in <IN HERE>

Comment: Look at code ..

Comment: So just place the category ID in there. What is the problem?

Comment: Not working....

Comment: “Not working” is less specific of an explanation than I hoped it would be. How are we supposed to help, not knowing anything about your category IDs, what you’ve tried, how exactly it’s not working, what errors it throws, and any more details? Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and provide your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Comment: I’m edited it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) to import your json file's data. Assuming the json file is of the same depth as your main js file:

```
let categoryList = require("./categorylist.json");
```

Then, you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to access properties in `oldState`. You did not provide your json data, and you seem to contradict yourself in "paste **a** category id in IN HERE" vs "IN HERE I need to insert **a list of** IDs", so I'm not entirely sure what you are asking for. Here's an example of that notation in your context though, and you can similarly loop through the array as neceessary:

```
let propertyName = categoryList[0];
oldState[propertyName].channels; //...
```

Also, I don't think "parameter" is the right term, the way you used it. Perhaps simply referring to it as a spot in your code would be more accurate. You could search up the definitions of parameters & arguments.